# Predicate and Verb

Tags: verbs, predicate

What is exactly the difference between Verb and Predicate ? could anybody please tell me clearly and give each example of both ? Thank you.

Comment: [Predicate is a logical concept](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf); it essentially means a semantic function that has one to three arguments. The prototype predicate is a verb, and the prototype argument is a noun, though there are other possibilities. Thus, logically, `Want` (_Bill_, `Shovel` (_Mary, Walk_)) means _Bill wants Mary to shovel the walk_; `Want` and `Shovel` are the predicates, and the nouns in italics are the arguments. It's just like calculus, only no numbers. Noun, on the other hand, is a grammatical term.

Answer (score 2):

A verb is a word class. And subject and predicate are the two main parts of a sentence. The predicate consists of a verb and its object(s) or when the verb is a linking verb as to be of verb and complement.

About.com has an article about the grammar term predicate.

http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/a/What-Is-A-Predicate.htm

A sentence makes a statement, a complete statement, and consists of the two parts, subject and predicate. The subject is the part about which a statement is made (a person, a thing, something abstract)  and the predicate is the part that contains what is said about the subject.

Grammars today tend to avoid the term predicate. Sentences are often analysed as subject verb object or subject verb complement.

In this type of analysis the term verb, which is a word class, is used  as sentence part, which actually is improper use of a grammar term. It would be better to use a new term eg verbal part. But often grammar terms are not used with the same precision as in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

The predicate of a sentence is the verb and its objects, complements, and modifiers (if any). Look at these example sentences:

John is sleeping. [The verb and predicate are identical: *is sleeping*.]

Mary likes coffee. [The verb is *likes*. The predicate is *likes coffee*.]

Sally takes her coffee with cream and sugar. [The verb is *takes*. The predicate is *takes her coffee with cream and sugar*.]

Comment: Would you consider *...even though she's lactose-intolerant* part of the predicate?

Comment: If it modifies the verb, yes, it is part of the predicate. I assume you simply want to tack that phrase onto the end of the third example I gave. In that case, it would be part of the predicate.